# Creating a input field using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have 2 buttons setup in my html file.

```
<div class="login-register">
            <button type="button" id="login" onclick="login()">Login</button>
            <button type="button" id="register">Register</button>
</div><!-- end of login-register -->
```

I would like to use javascript in conjunction with these buttons, so that when login is clicked.  then the buttons are hidden and 2 input fields such as,

```
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<input id="password" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

appear. I am using an internal script tag and all I have so far is,

```
$("#login").click(function(){
        var usernameInputField = document.createElement("login");
        usernameInputField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        usernameInputField.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Username');
        usernameInputField.setAttribute('name', 'username');
    })
```

I am not sure if this is good practice or if there is another preferred way to set this up.

Comment: Create an input with createElement not 'login', then it's good.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure `JavaScript` I would suggest just manipulating the styles.

It would look something like this

```
YourElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Is this best practice? I think it all depends on your application. But in a simple thing like this it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the possibility to replace, either the inner html or the entire div.

For example

```
$("#login").on('click',function(){
     $('.login-register').html('<input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><input id="password" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">');
});
```

Though, your password input should be of type `password`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#login").click(function(){

        document.getElementById("login-register").style.visibility = "hidden";

        document.getElementById("username-password").style.visibility = "visible";

    })
```